# Spawning an infinite amount of prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, runner

I have been trying to learn Unity 3D by creating a simple runner game.
The game was spawning a simple road from asset store. I have decided to add some obstacles to that road and make a prefab from it, but when I added that prefab to an array from which Unity takes prefabs to instantiate them and ran the game no prefabs were instantiated. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject[] amountOfPrefabs;
private Transform playerTransform;
private float spawnZ = 0.0f;
private float tileLength = 30.0f;
private int amnTileOnScreen = 7;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    for (int i = 0; i < amnTileOnScreen; i++)
    {
        SpawnTile();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (playerTransform.position.z > (spawnZ - amnTileOnScreen * tileLength))
    {
        SpawnTile();
    }
}

private void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = -1)
{
    GameObject go;
    go = Instantiate(amountOfPrefabs[0]) as GameObject;
    go.transform.SetParent(transform);
    go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
    spawnZ += tileLength;
}
}
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Where do you initialize and populate the GameObject[] array?

Comment: It is initialized on the 8th line “public GameObject amountOfPrefabs;”

Comment: right... thats the Declaration, I'm looking for amountOfPrefabs = GameObject[xx]; also are you sure the amountOfPrefabs[0] has object in there? Do you get any error durring the SpawnTile()?

Comment: @S.Fragkos That is filled in the inspector via drag and drop.

Comment: @Vit Did you check if `SpawnTile` is actually called? Add a `Debug.Log` statement to it. Aside from that there are a couple of things that you should not do the way you did (e.g. you would build up a lot of objects and you should not parent the objects because every newly added child will cause the whole container to get updated/iterated in the current versions of unity). Extra keyword here: object pooling.

Comment: @Gunnar B. SpawnTile is actually added

Comment: You mean called? Do the objects show up in the hierarchy? Maybe the parent is at some off position so you don't see the objects in game view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something was wrong with Unity3D, because when I created the same GameObject with the same script it started working